# Showing closure under addition for $\mathcal{Q}$: set of quadratic forms on $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: vector-spaces, quadratic-forms

In my lecture notes it says that:

> The set $\mathcal{Q}$ of all quadratic forms on $\Bbb R^n
> $ is a subspace of the vector space V of all functions
>   $f : \mathbb{R}^n → \mathbb{R}.$ (Recall that there is a one-to-one correspondence between quadratic forms and
>   symmetric matrices.)

I was just curious how one would go about showing this?
I.e., closure under addition, scalar multiplication and non-emptiness?

I think if someone can show me closure under either addition or scalar multiplication, I can figure out the rest, but I'm just stuck trying to start on this.

Comment: The first step is writing out a precise definition of $Q$ you want to use. It will be downhill from there.

Comment: A quadratic form is a function of the form $q(x) = \sum_{i,j} c_{ij} x_i x_j$. The $\Bbb{R}$-linear combinations of quadratic forms are quadratic forms, thus it is a $\Bbb{R}$ vector space. Writing $q(x) = \sum_{i \le j} C_{ij} x_i x_j$ shows its dimension is $n(n+1)/2$.

Comment: Hint: every element of $Q$ can be associated with an $n\times n$ matrix.